# convert c# to vb.net webbrowser

Tags: c#, vb.net

am trying to convert this c# to vb.net that has a webbrowser control, but am confused. the code is in a usercontrol.

c#

```
 private void SetupEvents()
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigated += new WebBrowserNavigatedEventHandler(webBrowser1_Navigated);
        webBrowser1.GotFocus += new EventHandler(webBrowser1_GotFocus);
    }

 [Browsable(true)]
    public override Color BackColor
    {
        get
        {
            return base.BackColor;
        }
        set
        {
            base.BackColor = value;
            if (ReadyState == ReadyState.Complete)
            {
                SetBackgroundColor(value);
            }
        }
    }



public HtmlDocument Document
        {
            get { return webBrowser1.Document; }
        }
```

the error
'Public Event Navigated(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs)' is an event, and cannot be called directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event.

please help

Comment: Only the first method in the "C#" example is actually C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code:

```
Private Sub SetupEvents()
    AddHandler webBrowser1.Navigated, AddressOf Me.webBrowser1_Navigated
    AddHandler webBrowser1.GotFocus, AddressOf Me.webBrowser1_GotFocus
End Sub    
<Browsable(true)>  _
Public Overrides Property BackColor As Color
    Get
        Return MyBase.BackColor
    End Get
    Set
        MyBase.BackColor = value
        If (ReadyState = ReadyState.Complete) Then
            SetBackgroundColor(value)
        End If
    End Set
End Property

Public ReadOnly Property Document As HtmlDocument
    Get
        Return webBrowser1.Document
    End Get
End Property

Private Sub SetupEvents()
    AddHandler webBrowser1.Navigated, AddressOf Me.webBrowser1_Navigated
    AddHandler webBrowser1.GotFocus, AddressOf Me.webBrowser1_GotFocus
End Sub
```

Comment: @JAiro for the second sub, i get this error:> > Readystate is a type and cannot be used as an expression

Comment: @Jairo i have an enum  `Public Enum ReadyState` and a property `public ReadyState ReadyState`

Comment: The compilator is confusing your Property ReadyState with the enum called ReadyState, try to rename the property and  try it again.

Comment: can cou convert this  `private void LinkDialog_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = URL;
            BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                linkEdit.Focus();
            });
        }`

Comment: try this: Private Sub LinkDialog_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        label1.Text = URL
        BeginInvoke((MethodInvokerUnknown, delegate, {, linkEdit.Focus)
    End Sub

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the webBrowser1_Navigated and webBroswer1_GotFocus are methods within this same class, then in the SetupEvents() method:

```
AddHandler WebBrowser1.Navigated, AddressOf webBrowser1_Navigated
AddHandler WebBrowser1.GotFocus, AddressOf webBrowser1_GotFocus
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the [`AddHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) keyword rather than += to set up your event handlers.